# How to give only one Bootstrap column control over height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, flexbox

I currently have a page layout which has one column representing a nav, and another column which represents the content.

```css
.bg-1{
  background-color:orange;
  height: 400px;
  overflow-y: auto;


}
.bg-2{
  background-color: red;
  height: 200px

}
.row{
  align-items:flex-start;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class='container'>

  <div class='row'>
    <div class='col-3 bg-1'>
    Nav<br/>
    Hello<br/>
    Hello<br/>
    Hello<br/>
    I need a scrollbar!<br/>
    And only be as tall as my red neighbor!
    
    
    </div>
    <div class='col-9 bg-2'>Content<br/>I can be as tall as I want!</div>
  
  
  </div>




</div>
```

Now, I don't mind the content div (red) increasing in content and taking more height. The nav should also follow suit and grow in height with the content div.

However, the nav too sometimes grows quite large. The problem is that it forces the user to scroll pass the content to the bottom of the nav. I would rather it listen to the content's height and use a scrollbar for any overfill.

How should I setup my css so the content div can grow the whole flex container as much as it needs while the nav is locked to the height of the content div and uses a scrollbar for its overflow?

I tried:

- Setting a max height to the parent container. It doesn't limit the nav div
- Setting a max height to the nav div. I can't find a value that lets it match to the content div.
- Using align-items: flex-start. This only stops the content div from growing but the user still has to stroll past the content div to the bottom of the nav. I want focus to be on the content so the navbar should use a scroll bar if it's larger than the content div.

Thank you!

Comment: I added an answer, is it what you was looking for ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to do this using using another `div` inside the left column. The inner `div` should be `position:absolute`...

Demo: https://codeply.com/p/TvjnlB0BTj

```css
.bg-1{
  background-color:orange;
}

.bg-2{
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class='container'>
    <div class='row'>
        <div class='col-3 bg-1 overflow-auto'>
            <div class="position-absolute">
            Nav<br /> 
            Hello<br /> 
            Hello<br /> 
            Hello<br /> 
            Hello<br /> 
            Hello<br /> 
            Hello<br /> 
            Hello<br /> 
            Hello<br /> 
            Hello<br /> 
            I need a scrollbar!<br /> 
            And only be as tall as my red neighbor!
                        
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='col-9 bg-2'>
            Content<br />I can be as tall as I want!
            <p>Shoreditch vegan artisan Helvetica. Tattooed Codeply Echo Park Godard kogi, next level irony ennui twee squid fap selvage. Meggings 
flannel Brooklyn literally small batch, mumblecore PBR try-hard kale chips. Brookch-key Odd Future. Austin messenger bag normcore, 
Helvetica Williamsburg sartorial tote bag distillery Portland before they sold out gastropub taxidermy Vice.</p>
            <p>Tattooed Codeply Echo Park Goda taxidermy Vice.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://codeply.com/p/TvjnlB0BTj

Comment: can you help me? https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212256/room-for-nisharg-shah-and-zim

Comment: Wow! This is so elegant and clever. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

you just need to add the same `height` for each div.

Try this :

```css
#div1{
  background-color:orange;
  height: 300px;
}

#div2{
  background-color: red;
  height: 300px;
}
.row{
  align-items:flex-start;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class='container'>

  <div class='row'>
    <div id="div1" class='col-3'>
    Nav<br/>
    Hello<br/>
    Hello<br/>
    Hello<br/>
    I need a scrollbar!<br/>
    And only be as tall as my red neighbor!
    
    
    </div>
    <div id="div2" class='col-9'>Content<br/>I can be as tall as I want!</div>
  
  
  </div>




</div>
```

Comment: Not exactly, giving them both the same height prevents the content div from expanding. I want the content div to grow as much as it wants with the nav following suite. I just don't want the nav to have control over height and use a scrollbar if its too tall.

Thanks for the answer tho!

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not possible with CSS so, I used `JS` here

```js
function divHeight() {
  let orgHeight = $('.right').height();
  let currentHeight = $('.left');
  $(currentHeight).css('height', orgHeight);
}

window.onload = function() {
  divHeight();
};

$(window).resize(function() {
  divHeight();
});
```

```css
.bg-1 {
  background-color: orange;
  overflow: auto;
}

.bg-2 {
  background-color: red;
  height: 200px
}

.row {
  align-items: flex-start;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class='container'>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='col-3 bg-1 left'>
      Nav<br/> Hello
      <br/> Hello
      <br/> Hello
      <br/> I need a scrollbar!<br/> And only be as tall as my red neighbor!
    </div>
    <div class='col-9 bg-2 right'>Content<br/>I can be as tall as I want!</div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```